# How I can make an attribute of the child model required, if it is inheriting the User class without saving?

Tags: python, django

like http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/
but can anyone suggest how I can make an attribute of the child model required, if it is inheriting the User class without saving the user if the instance of the child model is not saved? eg.

```
class Customer(User):
organization = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique = True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
.
..
objects = UserManager()
```

If in the admin.py, model Customer is registered, on execution, we get the user creation form, with password after saving it, we exit from the module. We are able to see that the user exists in the django Auth, even if the Customer is not yet created. How do I override the save of the User class. Also I need to create other users for the application the normal way. Please suggest

Comment: Please dont put hyperlinks in titles.

Comment: Putting the hyperlink in the title makes it completely useless as a title.  Consider it so bad that the owner of the site (Jeff Atwood) fixed it for you

Comment: Thanx, realised the folly Mike..

Answer (score 1):

You're sure you're not adding an User, not a Customer. Here you are not transforming users into customers, just creating a new class. (I misread your post and thought you missed that ; I'll leave that here but anyways).

You probably don't want *all* users to be customers (For instance, you have staff).

Did you try removing the manager ?

Let me point out however that the Django developers themselves recommend using profiles not inheritance (See comments from James Benett in the blog article you linked).

Comment: All I want to do is create a user instance along with the customer instance at the same time. If the customer is not created, I don't want to save the user either. I have tried removing the manager also.